# How to create comma separated string from using this kind of a two dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a two dimensional array like this

```
$FrstArr = Array(
    [0]= array(
                [0]=>101,
                [1]=>ename1,
                [2]=>1110
            ),

    [1]= array(
                [0]=>102,
                [1]=>ename2,
                [2]=>1111
            ),

    [2]= array(
                [0]=>103,
                [1]=>ename3,
                [2]=>1112
             )
)
```

From this array I need to create one single dimensional array like this

```
$secondArr = array([0]=>1110,[1]=>1111,[2]=>1112);
```

With out using any loops how can I create $secondArr array using $FrstArr multidimensional array? Any php built in functionality is available for that?

Comment: Whats the matter with loops? :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$secondArr = array_map(function ($i) { return $i[2]; }, $FrstArr);
```

This loops as well, but behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$secondArr = array_map(
  function ($item) { return $item[2]; },
  $firstArr
);
```

Worth to mention, that this will also (internally) loop over the array.

Comment: You're mixing up the parameter order for `array_map`. :)

Comment: @deceze You are right. I often mix it up with the parameter order of `array_walk()` ...